# How to authentication multi-user

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I was reading the docs on authentication with composer rest server here: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication.html and https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/enabling-multiuser.html and they set alice1 as the default identity for the default wallet
what if i have a multi-user app? how can I make every user use their own identity instead of the default alice1? For example bob1.

Answer (score 0):

when you are running in Multi user mode each user will be authenticated ; eg for example a GitHub ID (or - other passport enabled strategy). Each user will have a separate Wallet. All requests made by that authenticated user will use their own identity in Composer.

The best approach is to issue new identities linked to Participants in Composer and use the secret (generated) the first time. Those doc links you added, show how you enable Authentication on your REST server and then configure Multiuser mode. (You need to enable Authentication,  before configuring Multiuser mode). After setting an identity as the default for each wallet separately, it remains the default for that session.

A client of a REST API (eg a Web application) can have one or more wallets on the REST server to store identities in. Each wallet can contain one or more identities. The client can specify a default wallet, and a default identity in a wallet, and those will be used by default to handle any REST API calls from that client.

The Composer REST server uses open source Passport authentication strategies. You can look at the Passport website and see what other options (strategies) are there that might suit you - http://passportjs.org

Comment: Would it be possible to use identity cards for authentication instead of existing passportJs strategies?